# Custom authentication domain service - Silverlight and RIA

Tags: authentication, silverlight-4.0, forms-authentication, ria

I'm trying to write custom authentication domain service. I think I understood all code which was written on [this blog](http://www.astaticstate.com/2010/04/silverlight-custom-authentication.html).

However I don't know how to specify which domain service application should use. I have one abstract domain service and second one is a concrete implementation of this service. If I build entire solution I get an error

```
'MainModule.Web.FormsAuthenticationService`1' is not a valid DomainService type. DomainService types cannot be abstract or generic.
```

I didn't find source code on blog which I mentioned before.

```
namespace MainModule.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;



    // TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public abstract class FormsAuthenticationService<TUser> : DomainService, IAuthentication<TUser> where TUser : UserBase
    {

        protected abstract TUser GetCurrentUser(string name, string userData);
        protected abstract TUser ValidateCredentials(string name, string password, string customData, out string userData);
        protected virtual TUser GetDefaultUser()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public TUser GetUser()
        {
            IPrincipal currentUser = ServiceContext.User;
            if ((currentUser != null) && currentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsIdentity userIdentity = currentUser.Identity as FormsIdentity;
                if (userIdentity != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = userIdentity.Ticket;
                    if (ticket != null)
                    {
                        return GetCurrentUser(currentUser.Identity.Name, ticket.UserData);
                    }
                }
            }

            return GetDefaultUser();
        }

        public TUser Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData)
        {
            string userData;
            TUser user = ValidateCredentials(userName, password, customData, out userData);

            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(/* version */ 1, userName,
                                                           DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                           isPersistent,
                                                           userData,
                                                           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                HttpContextBase httpContext = (HttpContextBase)ServiceContext.GetService(typeof(HttpContextBase));
                httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContextBase httpContext = (HttpContextBase)ServiceContext.GetService(typeof(HttpContextBase));
                httpContext.AddError(new FormsAuthenticationLogonException("Username or password is not correct."));
            }

            return user;
        }

        public TUser Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return GetDefaultUser();
        }

        public void UpdateUser(TUser user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

namespace MainModule.Web
    {
        using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
        // TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
        [EnableClientAccess()]
        public class CustomAuthenticationService :FormsAuthenticationService<UserDTO>
        {
            protected override UserDTO GetCurrentUser(string name, string userData)
            {
                return new UserDTO {DisplayName = name, Name = name};
            }

            protected override UserDTO ValidateCredentials(string name, string password, string customData, out string userData)
            {
                userData = null;
                UserDTO user = null;


               if(name=="John" && password = "123")
               {
                    userData = name;
                    user =  new UserDTO {DisplayName = name, Email = "asdf"};

                 }
              retrurn user;
            }
        }
    }
```

This are classes I implemeted - it's the same code which is posted on blog. There is no exception so I can't paste an stackTrace. I just can't compile the solution

Comment: Let's see your code and full stack trace of the error message.

Comment: @RamiA. I edited my question.Notice that I can't build the solution so I can't paste stacktrace

Comment: Which line does the compiler error point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct namespaces.

I noticed two small typos in the code that you pasted:

1. `if(name=="John" && password = "123")`
   Should be:
   `if (name=="John" && password == "123")`
2. `retrurn user;`
   Should be:
   `return user;`

Otherwise, it compiles without errors for me.

1. Create a new Web Application
2. Add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting` (ex. from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll")
3. Add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server` (ex. from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll")
4. Create a class called `CustomAuthenticationService` and insert the code below.

   ```
   using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Security;
   using System;
   using System.Security.Principal;
   using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;
   using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ApplicationServices;

   namespace WebApplication1.Services
   {
       public class UserDTO : UserBase
       {
           public string DisplayName { get; set; }
           public string Email { get; set; }
       }

       public class FormsAuthenticationLogonException : System.Exception
       {
           public FormsAuthenticationLogonException(string message) : base(message) { }
       }

       // TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
       [EnableClientAccess()]
       public abstract class FormsAuthenticationService<TUser> : DomainService, IAuthentication<TUser> where TUser : UserBase
       {

           protected abstract TUser GetCurrentUser(string name, string userData);
           protected abstract TUser ValidateCredentials(string name, string password, string customData, out string userData);
           protected virtual TUser GetDefaultUser()
           {
               return null;
           }

           public TUser GetUser()
           {
               IPrincipal currentUser = ServiceContext.User;
               if ((currentUser != null) && currentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
               {
                   FormsIdentity userIdentity = currentUser.Identity as FormsIdentity;
                   if (userIdentity != null)
                   {
                       FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = userIdentity.Ticket;
                       if (ticket != null)
                       {
                           return GetCurrentUser(currentUser.Identity.Name, ticket.UserData);
                       }
                   }
               }

               return GetDefaultUser();
           }

           public TUser Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData)
           {
               string userData;
               TUser user = ValidateCredentials(userName, password, customData, out userData);

               if (user != null)
               {
                   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(/* version */ 1, userName,
                                                          DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                          isPersistent,
                                                          userData,
                                                          FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                   string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                   HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                   HttpContextBase httpContext = (HttpContextBase)ServiceContext.GetService(typeof(HttpContextBase));
                   httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
               }
               else
               {
                   HttpContextBase httpContext = (HttpContextBase)ServiceContext.GetService(typeof(HttpContextBase));
                   httpContext.AddError(new FormsAuthenticationLogonException("Username or password is not correct."));
               }

               return user;
           }

           public TUser Logout()
           {
               FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
               return GetDefaultUser();
           }

           public void UpdateUser(TUser user)
           {
               throw new NotImplementedException();
           }
       }

       // TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.
       [EnableClientAccess()]
       public class CustomAuthenticationService : FormsAuthenticationService<UserDTO>
       {
           protected override UserDTO GetCurrentUser(string name, string userData)
           {
               return new UserDTO { DisplayName = name, Name = name };
           }

           protected override UserDTO ValidateCredentials(string name, string password, string customData, out string userData)
           {
               userData = null;
               UserDTO user = null;


               if (name == "John" && password == "123")
               {
                   userData = name;
                   user = new UserDTO { DisplayName = name, Email = "asdf" };

               }

               return user;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

remove attribute  `[EnableClientAccess()]` from the FormsAuthenticationService abstract class.
it will compile without any error